# Access a CraftCMS 3 site that someone else built?

Tags: craft3

I'm trying to gain access to a Craft CMS site for a client that someone else built. We have access to the admin panel to edit content but I'm wondering how I would go about gaining access to the site files to make edits to the code and structure of the site? We don't have access to the person that originally built the site so we're at a bit of a loss on what to do next.

Answer (score 2):

I would try to get hold of the person who built the site, because the production environment may or may not include everything you need to make changes to the site. Even if it does, depending on the contract your client has with the original developer, the source code may be their copyright to which they've granted them a licence. In this case, modifying that code or using it for something else may even get you in legal trouble.

Try to get access to the person who built the site and find out if there is some sort of version control (i.e. a git repository). If there is, try to get a copy of the repository – this has all you need to continue working on the project. If there isn't, ask if there's a development version of the site and ask for an archive (zip file). At the very least, try to find out if the production site includes all the files required to continue to work on it (this depends on how the site is deployed to the production server). I would also find out how the site is hosted and deployed, and if there is an existing deployment pipeline that you can use. Otherwise, deploying any changes is going to be painful and unnecessary manual work.

If you have no other choice, you need access to the source files and, if possible, the database as well. The website has to be hosted somewhere, and someone is paying for that hosting. If the hosting contract is in the name of your client, they either already have some form of access to the server (SSH or FTP) or they can get credentials from the hosting provider. If the hosting contract is in the name of the developer, you may still need to contact them to gain access. In this case, I would try to get the hosting transferred to an account under your client's control, because if the developer stops paying, the site will stop working.

Once you have SSH or FTP access, you can download all the source files from the server. But again, this may or may not include everything you need. In the future, tell your client to have contingency plans, so they don't lose access to their site or the ability to update it due to the [bus factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor).

Comment: Agreed, this is your best (maybe only) path forward. Assuming you truly can't reach the original developer (unfortunate, because it makes everything else harder), you will need to access the website via its hosting account.